# Best tool to generate normal distribution graph in java or jquery

Tags: java, jquery, normal-distribution

I want to generate **normal distribution** graph for a set of values as in the [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Standard_deviation_diagram.svg),I have tried using `JFreeChart` but could not get the desired output [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19357905/how-to-give-a-different-color-for-each-sigma-section).so asking a new question,hope our stack users will give suggestions.

Is there any way to generate the graph as it is in the link with **java** or **jquery** from the calculated mean and standard deviation?

Answer (score 0):

As this picture is generated from R, one option could be to execute appropriate 'R command' from java. Second option can be [JavaPlot](http://vase.essex.ac.uk/software/JavaPlot/) (although I haven't tried it, read about it in [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703150/draw-gaussian-curve-in-java). )